# Validation stages

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am validating with Cake 3 but can't get it working probably.
As the docs says there are two stages of validating:

> Before you save your data you will probably want to ensure the data is correct and consistent. In CakePHP we have two stages of validation:
>
> - Before request data is converted into entities, validation rules around data types and formatting can be applied.
> - Before data is saved, domain or application rules can be applied. These rules help ensure that your application’s data remains consistent.

So, if I understand this right, at first validation rules are used when I pass data via `newEntity` and `patchEntity`.
After that, the application rules are used when using `save` or `delete`.

However, when I am passing data (an array) via `newEntity` the application rules are never used (`buildRules` is never called). When using `newEntity` without passing data, application rules are used!

So, my first question, is it right that not both rules are runned, only one (OR validation rules, OR application rules?). I would expect that first validation rules would be called to check the input, and before saving, ALSO the application rules would be called to check if the entity is valid to the applicaton.

Second question, how should I validate with my API? The actions pass their data via the `newEntity` method, but I want to check if (for example) the `category_id` belongs to the same user. Thats typical an application rule I guess?

Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#creating-a-default-validation-set):

> Validation objects are intended primarily for validating user input, i.e. forms and any other posted request data.

Basically, validation is done when you use `newEntity` or `patchEntity` to check that the incoming data is consistent:

- You don't have a random string where you should have a number
- The user email is of correct format
- Standard and confirmation passwords are equals
- etc.

Validation is **not** done when you set field manually:

```
$user->email = 'not a valid email' ; // no validation check
```

Basically, validation rules are meant to tell the user « Hey, you did something wrong! ».

**Application rules** on the other end are always checked when you call `save` or `delete`, these may be used for:

- Checking uniqueness of a field
- Checking that a foreign key exist - There is an `Group` that correspond to your `group_id`
- etc.

Your first assumption is somehow false because in the following scenario, both validation and application rules are checked:

```
$article = $this->Articles->newEntity($this->request->data);
$this->Articles->save($article) ;
```

[This part](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/validation.html#validation-vs-application-rules) of the documentation explain the difference between the two layers of validation.

---

Concerning your second question, you should not check that a user has the right to do something in your model, this should be done by your controller, see [CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The poiny I tried to make is that in my code, validation rules AND application rules are not runned both. It's one or the other. The docs make clear both should be runned (1 on newEntity, 1 on save). My second question is not about rights and roles, but a check of provided data. For example when someone posts a new blog and contains a `category_id`, I should check that the provided category_id is owned by the user. It's something like `existsIn` but only extended :P

Comment: @Bob Well, it will be difficult for me to help you without your code. Concerning your `category_id`, this is clearly a problem of rights and roles since you talk about "ownership", i.e. "Who has the right to post new post in this category?". These check should be done by the Controller, not the model, see CakePHP doc (last link in my answer), which is almost same as your question ("Who is allowed to modify this article?").

Comment: I am familiar with cake so I know that's controller stuff. I've found out that the `buildRules` isn't called when my validation contains the `requirePresence` rule... This sounds very strange to me?